# Can I use 2 WordPress databases inside one single MySQL database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

One of my clients wants that he has only one SQL database in that he wants to run 2 different SQL WordPress databases.

Is there any solution? thanks in advance..

Comment: What do you mean? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have one database with two (and more) WordPress instances (sites, blogs) where each instance must use different table prefix.

See here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress and look for this sentence:

> If you have only one database and it is already in use, you can
>   install WordPress in it - just make sure to have a distinctive prefix
>   for your tables to avoid over-writing any existing database tables.

Here you can find more info how to do it: https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs#Single_Database

In shortcut there is a *wp-config.php* file which will vary for each installation on this line:

```
$table_prefix = 'wp_';
```

Where `wp_` is a default value but you should use different value here for each WordPress instance. For example for the first instance there will be:

```
$table_prefix = 'first_';
```

... and for the second instance:

```
$table_prefix = 'second_';
```

Then you will have in one MySQL database two sets of tables one prefixed by `first_` and the second by `second_`.